# Extracting the date from a .txt file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.7

I have a .txt file. It contains a few dates. The one I'm looking is preceded by words: "Date: dd.MM.yy Hour: HH:mm". I tried to match it by

```
 matches=re.findall(r'Date:\s\d\d.\d\d.\d{4}\sHour:\s\d\d:\d\d', text)
```

but I need to extract only numbers in specific format- "dd.MM.yy HH:mm". The file contains also a few other dates- I don't see another way to match it tha. Now I'm obviously getting  "Date: 28.10.2018 Hour: 11:00".

1) Is there a better way to search in the .txt file?

2) How to extract both date and hour from the string, omitting words?

Comment: Please tag this question with `regex` for more relevant visibility

Comment: Some examples of the input might help.

Comment: Please add the string and the expected output from it so that we can answer better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [capture groups](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html#grouping) to get the information you're interested in:

```
import re
s = "Date: 11.19.2018 Hour: 15:23"
matches = re.findall(r'Date: (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}) Hour: (\d{2}:\d{2})', s)
```

The variable `matches` will then contain:

```
[('11.19.2018', '15:23')]
```

Comment: if you use a group for each number you can get directly the individual numbers to build properly a Date, e.g. `r'Date: (\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}) Hour: (\d{2}):(\d{2})'`